# How to add attachments in AbstractMailService

Tags: shopware, shopware6

We are developing custom plugin. The idea is create route which our PWA will use for sending contact form data (name, surname and so on) but the data also have attachments like pdf, png.

So questions how I can add the attachment which I will receive from the route using AbstractMailService?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `binAttachments` key for adding an array of binary data to be attached to the mail.

```php
$data = [
    'recipients' => [
        'test@example.com' => 'Foobar',
    ],
    'senderName' => '...',
    'salesChannelId' => '98432def39fc4624b33213a56b8c944d',
    'templateId' => '4240c8634a584846853cd6ddea7cc94b',
    'customFields' => null,
    'contentHtml' => '...',
    'contentPlain' => '...',
    'subject' => '...',
    'mediaIds' => [],
    'binAttachments' => [
        [
            'content' => $binaryData,
            'fileName' => 'foo.bar',
            'mimeType' => '...',
        ],
    ],
];

$this->container->get(MailService::class)->send($data, $context);
```